# I got an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'producer' of undefined" in Tensorflowjs tf.loadGraphModel

Tags: javascript, tensorflow

I am doing Fine-Tuning using ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29 on Google Colab.
I am in trouble because the model converted by Tensorflowjs_converter cannot be read by Javascript.

tensorflowjs==1.3.1

```
tensorflowjs_converter \
    --input_format=tf_saved_model \
    --output_format=tfjs_graph_model \
    --output_node_names='num_detections,detection_boxes,detection_scores,detection_classes,detection_masks' \
    --signature_name=serving_default \
    --saved_model_tags=serve \
    ./saved_model \
    ./web_model
```

Listing of "web_model" derectory

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4194304 Nov  2 03:24 group1-shard1of5.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4194304 Nov  2 03:24 group1-shard2of5.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4194304 Nov  2 03:24 group1-shard3of5.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4194304 Nov  2 03:24 group1-shard4of5.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1753480 Nov  2 03:24 group1-shard5of5.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  303953 Nov  2 03:24 model.json
```

HTML

...
var model = await tf.loadGraphModel('https://domain/web_model/model.json');

Error

> tfjs@1.3.1:2 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'producer' of undefined
>       at t. (tfjs@1.3.1:2)
>       at tfjs@1.3.1:2
>       at Object.next (tfjs@1.3.1:2)
>       at o (tfjs@1.3.1:2)

I don't know if the cause is the version or the conversion is bad. If you know anyone, please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

try `loadLayersModel`:

```js
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('https://domain/web_model/model.json')
```

took from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/1432#issuecomment-475425261)